# High CPU usage of threads reading synchronously from yet to be filled resources

Tags: windows, winapi, cpu-usage, winsockets

(Working on win32/c++ environment)

I have a function that calls `ReadFile` (synchronously) with a fixed size of one byte to read from a `SOCKET` resource (of `WINSOCK`).
There's multiple threads running this function. 
The data is written to sockets externally, and is not on my control. 
whenever the data is yet to be written, I find my `exe` consuming nearly 80% of CPU, and the usage divide relatively equally among the mentioned threads (there are typically 4 of them).

as `ReadFile` is an OS api, I would have expected it to be implemented asynchronously internally to avoid such as issue. 
My question is why is this happening, and what can I do to avoid it.

Comment: Why are you using `ReadFile()` and not `recv()` or `WSARecv()`?

Answer (score 0):

it's been a very long time since I did Win32 programming, but I seem to remember that the ReadFile returns an error when there is no data to read from the socket. It might be returning 0 bytes read, or something.

Comment: no. it's blocking without a timeout, which is good for my use, except the CPU resources consumption issue.